# How mimikatz kerberous returns plain text credentials?

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos

I have the following environment:-

DC:- Windows server 2008

Victim: Windows 7

Attacker: windows 10

Now I compromised the windows 7 some way, then I load mimikatz in meterpreter.
Then, when I type Kerberos, it returns Kerberos credentials in plain text.

I was surprised that *How it returns credentials in plain text?*.And also I am looking for a way to encrypt them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected outcome. There are several sources to this:

http://woshub.com/how-to-get-plain-text-passwords-of-windows-users/

> For instance, HTTP Digest Authentication used to support SSO (Single
> Sign On) needs the user password along with its hash. Encrypted user
> passwords (passwords, instead of hashes) are stored in the OS memory,
> and, to be more specific, in LSASS.EXE process memory. The problem is
> that password encryption is implemented using the standard Win32
> functions LsaProtectMemory and LsaUnprotectMemory, which are used to
> encrypt/decrypt a certain area of memory. A tool of French developers
> mimikatz allows you to obtain the encrypted data from the memory,
> decrypt them using LsaUnprotectMemory function and display all
> accounts of users authorized in the system and their passwords
> (decrypted, in plain text!).

https://adsecurity.org/?p=556

> Since Windows encrypts most credentials in memory (LSASS), they should
> be protected, but it is a type of reversible encryption (though creds
> are in clear-text). Encrypt works with LsaProtectMemory and decrypt
> with LsaUnprotectMemory.
>
> NT5 encryption types: RC4 & DESx
>
> NT6 encryption types: 3DES & AES
>
> Mimikatz capabilities:
>
> Dump credentials from LSASS (Windows Local Security Account database)
> [sekurlsa module] MSV1.0: hashes & keys (dpapi)
>
> Kerberos password,
> ekeys, tickets, & PIN

And some background info:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/preventing-lsass-from-storing-clear-text-passwords-in-kerberos-environment

> It is a well known security risk that LSASS stores clear-text
> passwords if a user has performed a keyboard-interactive logon on a
> machine - be it local login to his/her workstation or using RDP to a
> remote workstation.

You can force disable this by using group policies or the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\WDigest\UseLogonCredential = 0`), but it could break some compatibility.

If your servers (2008) and clients (Win 7) are fully patched, there is also the way to use the `protected users` AD-group, which disables this "feature" for the included users.

Comment: Hi @Lenniey, I am on the windows 7 machine. So I want to confirm that what windows apply this method?